# Cannot create fragment using viewpager in an activity.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to add a `ViewPager` using `Fragment` to a portion of my main activity which extends `TabActivity`.
For this I have created a `ViewPagerActivity` class which extends `FragmentActivity` ,from here it adds the calls the `FragmentAdapter` which creates the `Fragment` which contains the view I want to create.
But the problem that I'm facing is I cannot get my main class to create the viewpager on my main activity.

I think the problem is when I'm calling the class `ViewPagerActivity` on my main class,which cannot create the `fragment` to create the `viewpager`.

Please help I've been stuck in this for almost a month now , each solution I try fails.
These codes run perfectly when they are implemented separately in a separate project but doesnot seems to execute when implemented in my project.

ViewPagerActivity class

```
class ViewPagerClass extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
    {
            TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
            ViewPager mviewpager;
            CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                mviewpager = new ViewPager(getApplicationContext());
                mviewpager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
                mviewpager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                mIndicator.setViewPager(mviewpager);
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
```

TestFragmentAdapter.java

```
class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
    protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "This", "Is", "A", "Test"};
    protected static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {};
    private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
         super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return TestFragmentAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
      return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

TestFragment.java

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";
    static TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
    public static TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(content).append("\n");
        fragment.mContent = builder.toString();
        return fragment;
    }
    private String mContent = "???";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {

            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagerframe, container);
        LayoutParams textparam = new LayoutParams(130,40);
        TestView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setText(mContent);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_ll);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layout.addView(text,textparam);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code finally worked with few changes here and there. I'd like to add them here to help other developers with same problem as mine.

> I need to add a ViewPager using Fragment to a portion of my main activity which extends TabActivity. For this I have created a ViewPagerActivity class which extends FragmentActivity ,from here it adds the calls the FragmentAdapter which creates the Fragment which contains the view I want to create. But the problem that I'm facing is I cannot get my main class to create the viewpager on my main activity.

- First I was not able to extend multiple class since i needed both `Fragment` and `TabActivity`
- I found somewhere we could extend `Tab`'s function also as Listener. Here's how I did it:

  ```
  public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,TabContentFactory{ }
  ```
- Then I wrote the code in my class `ViewPagerActivity` into the `Main`
- I guess this was the main problem. Anyways, I changed the code to create the `Bundle` in `TestFragment` class like this

  ```
  public static TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("content", content);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
   }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // the if clause wasnot working for me 
    mContent = getArguments().getString("content");
  }
  ```

  - Changed to `onCreate` to return view rather than the layout which I was missing earlier

    ```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagerframe, container,false);
     LayoutParams textparam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,30);
     TestView text = new TextView(getActivity());
     text.setText(mContent);
     text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pager_ll);
     layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     layout.addView(edtext,textparam);
     return view;
    }
    ```
  - After this everything worked well.

Answer (score 1):

you have forgot setting your content view so set your after initializing you ViewPager as View pager is your content view

```
setContentView(mviewpager);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,but the viewpager is just a part of the main view and even when i use addView(mviewpager) it didnot worked.

Comment: if view pager is only a part its easy to define in xml file. Bdw your code should return view containing TextView which should display your mContent (check your mcontent weather it is empty or null if so your view display nothing); i suggest you to set a static text first